# Columns to display in table view

Tags: cognito-forms

When I change the columns to display on my Form table of entries, the table always reverts back to the default 1st columns of the form when I reopen the table.

How do I get my selected/preferred columns to "stick" (stay in place)?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/). This is a feature that we have been discussing internally and will be looking into for future releases. We have added this to our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/j8l6lYlj) so our users can track the progress of this.